# Provide a data mapping grid for exporting out of CRM 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a number of workflows for creating a custom data structure in SharePoint to use as a document storage location for CRM. I currently set metadata pre-defined in the workflow (using the dynamic workflow properties).

I would like to be able to use this workflow, but based on a value in an activity (i.e. Document Type) lookup a certain "mapping" in code, and then use it to map properties in CRM to SharePoint properties. I already have the code to do the assignment, but the current mapping is in a single field value on the workflow using a nasty mix of dynamic values and manually entered content type properties. e.g.

*{DynamicValue} : Content_0x00_Type_0x00Property | {AnotherValue} : Field*

I would like to create a data mapping similar to that of the import grid. A user could select an activity type, then map it's properties (one or more) to SharePoint fields.

Is there a control in CRM to leverage a grid where I can insert the dynamic CRM values like the workflow config to make this a lot easier?

Comment: Do you have a custom workflow activity to do that? If yes you can create a configuration entity and add your mappings there. From the CWA you can read the configuration entity (that can be an entity with just 2 text fields), and apply the proper trasformations/mappings

Comment: I do have a workflow that is run when an activity is set regarding the case. I already have a configuration entity. It's actually the UI for the configuration I'm struggling with. Currently it is done in one long text field. I would love a grid/table view. That a user can just keep adding rows to. Is that possible?

Comment: Usually the editable grids are third party solutions (as a subgrid somewhere in a form), the only other choice you have is to create a web resource and create everything via js and rest calls i think. That will give you room to implement whatever logic in the background and you will have many editable free grids alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would approach this by the following:

1. Create a new settings entity, with values for Type, and its properties.
2. Write a custom workflow activity that based on an input type (from the record in context) retrieves the relevant record.
3. In the workflow you can then call the CWA to dynamically access the record you need.

This avoids hardcoding, but means you have to create the settings records in each environment.